# How can i create dots loading view like as google loader?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I want to create custom dots loader like as google dots loader(below image).
I founded following library but it written in Kotlin language, I want exactly this loader view in java language.
Someone can help me? Thanks.
 [CirclesLoadingView](https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/CirclesLoadingView)
[image: dots loading view]

Comment: It doesn't matter that it is in Kotlin, you can include the library in your project and then include the layout in the XML as defined in the library's readme.

Comment: @Sharp Thanks. Don't need to config project for Kotlin and add Kotlin libraries to app build.gradle?

Comment: You don't need Kotlin, yes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment to the question, you can simply include the library in your project as follows:

In app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:CirclesLoadingView:1.0'
```

In root build.gradle (or settings.gradle if you define repositories there):

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

And finally, in the desired XML layout:

```
<me.ibrahimsn.lib.CirclesLoadingView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I tried this in a pure Java project and it works without any additions.

Comment: Thanks. But this library min sdk is 22 and my min is 19 and i don't want to increase min sdk. There are any other solution?

Comment: You could go with Glide as the other comment suggested. You can get the gif on the repository of the library - https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/CirclesLoadingView/blob/master/art/gif.gif

Comment: This gif not suitable. It isn't transparent and it's time is between one and two rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide library to load any gif image to image view

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Thanks. But i don't find high quality gif image for that.